# Remote access forbidden but localhost works with Apache

Tags: network, catalina, apache, webserver

I followed [this](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-apache-mysql-php-on-macos-catalina-10-15/) tutorial and the Apache server works locally. `http://localhost/~user/` works but remotely `http://my-ip/~user` I get:

```
Forbidden.
You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

Note that I am using the same computer. It used to work with Mojave. How can I fix this?

Comment: username.conf contains: *Require host localhost*!  Please check: [Apache Module mod_authz_host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By following the tutorial, you have created the file `/etc/apache2/users/username.conf` which contains the following:

```
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
AllowOverride All
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
Require host localhost
</Directory>
```

(note that you've replaced "username" with your actual username)

If you want to allow the public access to the folder, change it to look as follows:

```
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
AllowOverride All
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Note that the "`Require`" line was changed to "`Require all granted`".